# ¿como editar un dato de un registro en django?

Tags: django, django-forms

estoy intentando cambiar un dato desde mi frontend , solo un dato es el que quiero cambiar pero no me permite cambiarlo si no muestro todos los campos del formulario , el valor que quiero cambiar es el **estadoP**

```
Viwes.py

def proyect_detail(request, proyectos_id):
detail = get_object_or_404(Proyectos, pk=proyectos_id)
form = CreateProyectForm(instance=detail)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CreateProyectForm(request.POST, instance=detail)
    print(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.estadoP = request.POST['estadoP']
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
return render(request, 'home/proyect_detail.html', {
    'Detail': detail,
    'form': form,
})
```

Ese **print** me muestra el **request.POST**  que si se esta obteniendo el valor a cambiar  pero no logra guardarlo
El **detail** es para mostrar los datos que ya tengo y el **form** es para mostrar los imputs pero no me deja cambiar ese valor , estaba leyendo que debo de acceder al objeto y de ahi cambiar el valor pero no me deja , la unica forma que me ha dejado cambiar el valor es mostrando todos los Fields con un **{{ form.as_p }}** en mi HTML y ahi ya me deja cambiar el valor que necsito pero lo que quiero es solo mostrar el campo que quiero cambiar

El modelo es este :

```
class Proyectos(models.Model):
    estadoP = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ESTADO_CHOICE, default='1')
    nomnbreProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    problematica = models.TextField(max_length=700)
    justificacion = models.TextField(max_length=700)

    ESTADO_CHOICE = (
        ("1", "PendienteRevision"),
        ("2", "Aceptado"),
        ("3", "Rechgazado"),
```

y en mi HTML es lo siguiente:

```
<div class="card" >
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">Detalles Proyecto</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
            <h3 class="text-primary"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i> {{ Detail.nomnbreProyecto }}</h3>

            <div class="text-muted">
                <b class="d-block">Problematica</b>
                <p class="text-muted">{{ Detail.problematica }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text-muted">
                <b class="d-block">Justificacion</b>
                <p class="text-muted">{{ Detail.justificacion }}</p>
            </div>

                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.estadoP }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center mt-5 mb-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> 
                    Enviar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

este es mi forms.py:

```
class CreateProyectForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Proyectos
    fields = ['nomnbreProyecto', 'problematica', 'justificacion', 'estadoP']
```

Asi se ve en pantalla todo :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en el "fields" de tu form hay varios campos que son obligatorios. Porque así los tienes definidos en el model. Como no los estás enviando en el POST, nunca va a considerar que el form es válido.

Hay varias formas de arreglarlo, pero lo más sencillo en mi opinión sería modificar el views y no usar la función `form.is_valid()`. Sino cambiar el estado directamente en el objeto `detail`:

```
def proyect_detail(request, proyectos_id):
    detail = get_object_or_404(Proyectos, pk=proyectos_id)
    form = CreateProyectForm(instance=detail)
    if request.method == "POST":
        estadoP = request.POST.get('estadoP')
        detail.estadoP = estadoP
        detail.save()
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'home/proyect_detail.html', {
        'Detail': detail,
        'form': form,
    })
```

Comment: intenté sin ponerle el form is valid pero a la hora de correrlo me dice que tiene que calidad el formulario , la solución que encontré es hacer un nuevo form.model para cada conjunto de campos que tengo que guardar , no es la mejor opción pero ahí la llevo